# Remove first array set from within parent array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which holds many array sets. The first (outer) array has a key which changes. My goal is to enter the parent array (again, key unknown) and remove the first array set. The keys of the array sets increment from zero - ideally these would be reindexed.

I’ve considered using a foreach loop with an incrementing count, array_splice on the array itself.

The problem appears to be accessing the array sets when the key of the outer array is unknown. For example, the below code does not work to access the array sets (the key is named, just unknown or changeable).

```
foreach ($array[0] as $item)
{
    if ($i < 1)
    {
        unset($item[0]);
    }
    $i++;
}
```

If I use array_splice this could potentially remove the foreach.

Here is the original array:

```
            Array
            (
                [changeable] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Alpha
                                [score] => 1
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Beta
                                [score] => 1
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Gamma
                                [score] => 4
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Delta
                                [score] => 3
                            )

                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Epsilon
                                [score] => 2
                            )

                        [5] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Zeta
                                [score] => 2
                            )

                    )

            )
```

Here is expected array - note: 'alpha' array is removed, keys reindexed.

```
            Array
            (
                [changeable] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Beta
                                [score] => 1
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Gamma
                                [score] => 4
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Delta
                                [score] => 3
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Epsilon
                                [score] => 2
                            )

                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Zeta
                                [score] => 2
                            )

                    )

            )
```

Comment: Sounds like you may be looking for `array_shift`.

Comment: I can't even figure out what you're trying to do. Can you show an example of the input and desired result?

Comment: If you don't know the keys, you can use `array_keys()` to get them. You can also use functions like `reset()` and `key()`.

Comment: Updated with before and expected

Comment: Hey, you can simply use array_shift($array[changeable]), Here $array is your original array variable name

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) , if i understand your question properly.

```
$array = [];
        $array['random_key1'] = [
            [

                'name' => 'Alpha',
                'score' => 1
            ],
            [

                'name' => 'Beta',
                'score' => 1
            ],
            [

                'name' => 'Gamma',
                'score' => 4
            ],
            [

                'name' => 'Delta',
                'score' => 3
            ],
            [

                'name' => 'Epsilon',
                'score' => 2
            ],
            [

                'name' => 'Zeta',
                'score' => 2
            ]
        ];

 $array['random_key2'] = [
            [

                'name' => 'Alpha',
                'score' => 1
            ],
            [

                'name' => 'Beta',
                'score' => 1
            ],
            [

                'name' => 'Gamma',
                'score' => 4
            ],
            [

                'name' => 'Delta',
                'score' => 3
            ],
            [

                'name' => 'Epsilon',
                'score' => 2
            ],
            [

                'name' => 'Zeta',
                'score' => 2
            ]
        ];



foreach($array as &$value) {
  array_shift($value);
}


echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
```